# ItemTemplate from window resource not found

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a window which shows 2 lists, which should use the same template, so I thought about putting the template into a Resource in my Window like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="itemTemplateAsResourceTest:FeatureViewModel" x:Key="FeatureTemplate">
            <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <ListBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource FeatureTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding Features}"/>
</Grid>
```

`Features` is just a List of `FeatureViewModel` (I put it in my Mainwindow for the test App) and FeatureViewModel simply looks like this in my Test:

```
public class FeatureViewModel
{
    public string Name
    {
        get { return "Name"; }
    }
}
```

It works in the Designer, however when I start my App it says "Resource 'FeatureTemplate' not found. It can't be misspelling, because the Designer finds it! What have I done wrong?

When I put the Template directly into the ListBox, it works, but then I have do duplicate my Template:

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Features}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="itemTemplateAsResourceTest:FeatureViewModel">
                <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Renaming the Template or moving it directly to the Window's Resources didn't solve it, does anyone see my mistake?

**SOLUTION**

Changing

```
<DataTemplate DataType="itemTemplateAsResourceTest:FeatureViewModel" x:Key="FeatureTemplate">
```

to

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type itemTemplateAsResourceTest:FeatureViewModel}" x:Key="FeatureTemplate">
```

did the trick!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `DataType`. It is redundant, because you are already setting `x:Key`.

Besides that it is also wrongly written, because (as opposed to e.g. `Style.TargetType`) you must use the `{x:Type ...}` markup extension. Otherwise, the DataType property (which is of type `object`) is just set to the string you applied in XAML, but not to the `Type` you intended to set.

Comment: Shame on Resharper for not doing this right automatically! Tested again: It suggests the right Type, automatically adds the namespace, but forgets the x:Type!! Since i love to specify Datatypes to have auto-completion and warnings I prefer to add {x:Type ...} instead of leaving the Datatype empty...